# Chrome and Chrome Beta crash when synced - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: google-chrome, sync, 21.10, beta

After I turn profile sync on, Chrome crashes a few seconds after being started. Happens on Chrome - Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit), and Chrome Beta - Version 103.0.5060.24 (Official Build) beta (64-bit).

Running it from command line (google-chrome-beta), I see the following log:

```
[18432:18432:0530/084020.217092:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(105)] Error loading https://feedly.com/i/my
[18432:18432:0530/084020.217104:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(106)]   page redirected to https://feedly.com/i/welcome
[18475:18481:0530/084021.120655:ERROR:quic_ping_manager.cc(145)] QUIC retransmittable PING deadline is in past, now: 675127121, retransmittable_on_wire_deadline: 675126405, difference: 716us
[18475:18481:0530/084021.120688:ERROR:quic_ping_manager.cc(145)] QUIC retransmittable PING deadline is in past, now: 675127166, retransmittable_on_wire_deadline: 675126405, difference: 761us
[18475:18481:0530/084021.120704:ERROR:quic_ping_manager.cc(145)] QUIC retransmittable PING deadline is in past, now: 675127181, retransmittable_on_wire_deadline: 675126405, difference: 776us
[18432:18432:0530/084024.402927:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(105)] Error loading https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7
[18432:18432:0530/084024.402940:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(106)]   page redirected to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r#main_7
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[18432:18432:0530/084029.218181:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(105)] Error loading http://www.globes.co.il/portal/portfolio.aspx
[18432:18432:0530/084029.218194:ERROR:web_app_url_loader.cc(106)]   page redirected to https://www.globes.co.il/portal/portfolio.aspx
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I deleted the config folder (`rm -rf google-chrome-beta`) and signed in without sync and everything worked fine. Could post this question.

BTW, some of the links in the logs refer to very old links like feedly. But I guess this is another issue.

Also, there's an error about a `Fontconfig error`. Not sure if it's related either.

Ubuntu version: 21.10.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Whoever voted to close the issue, can you please explain?

Comment: I didn't vote, but close voting is because bug reports are off-topic here.

Comment: @Pilot6, thanks. The problem is that I don't know where the bug is. Perhaps it's in Ubuntu? Perhaps there's a missing library that somehow removed in the latest updates? The purpose of asking the question is to find a solution.

Comment: Most likely Chrome cache is corrupted. Try to clear it.